# Entity Framework Core app - how to show a DropDown List populated from a related model to the current model in Create & Edit pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm creating a ASP.NET Core (MVC) site with Entity Framework Core, which has tables for Products, Brands. Each Product must have a Brand, so the Products table has a BrandID field which is a key to the Brands table.

In the simple admin I have made for creating and editing Products, I want to display a DropDown with all the BrandNames from my Brands table.

My Create page has a field for the BrandID by using the following:

```
<label asp-for="BrandID" class="control-label"></label>
<input asp-for="BrandID" class="form-control" />
<span asp-validation-for="BrandID" class="text-danger"></span>
```

And the Controller action looks like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult>Create([Bind("ID,Name,Description,BrandID")] Product product)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(product);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(product);
}
```

I have no problem showing the name on my Product list page as I have access to the BrandNamefor each Product through my Index Controller action looking like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
     return View(await _context.Products.Include(b => b.Brand)
          .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync()); 
}
```

So, my question is what is the best way to show a DropDown with the full list of BrandNamesin my Brands table instead of a just textbox for the BrandID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of a for-each loop and hand the data over from the Controller via ViewBag:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
{
        var Product = await _context.Product.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ProductID == id).Include(p => p.Brand);
        ... //Your previous code 
        ViewBag.Brands = new SelectList(_context.Brands.ToList(),'ID','Name');

        //for edit make sure to set the current element as selected
        var selected = list.Where(brand => brand.BrandID== Product.Brand.BrandID).First();
        selected.Selected = true;
        return View(product);
}
```

```
<select asp-for="BrandID" 
            asp-items="@(ViewBag.Brands)">
           <!--Not for edit:-->        
           <option disabled selected>Please select one</option>
    </select>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, got that to work, thank you!!! Now to just make the stored Brand as the selected item when Editing a Product.